# how to create a hyperlink for values from an array in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-arrays

I have data that looks something like this

```
plans:[
  {
    "planName": "PlanA",
    "planCode": "PLN001"
  },
  { 
    "planName": "PlanB",
    "planCode": "PLN002"
  },
  {
    "planName": "PlanC",
    "planCode": "PLN003"
  }
]
```

I need to display in UI HTML like below

```
<p> User 1 is enrolled in PlanA , PlanB , PLanC </p>
```

question1: How to get the values from the plans array to display like above with commas in one statement.

question2: I need to give a hyperlink to each plan to the question1 statement which will take to a different component based on the plan code.

`<a href="#{planCode}_details">{{PlanName}}</a>`

The other components that the hyperlink has to take have an id to it

```
id="{{p.planCode}}_details"
```

Any help is appreciated

This is what I tried so far.

```
<p *ngIf="plans?.length > 0">{{UserName}} has a balance in the {{plans.planName.join(', ')}} .</p>
```

Comment: you can solve the first one using this `let a =''` and then map the plans array `plans.map(x=> a= a.concat(' ,',x.planCode))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1

```js
var plans = [ { "planName": "PlanA", "planCode": "PLN001" }, { "planName": "PlanB", "planCode": "PLN002" }, { "planName": "PlanC", "planCode": "PLN003" }]

var result = (plans.map(plan => plan.planName)).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + ', ' + curr)

console.log(result);
```

You could try the following to obtain a comma separated string of all `planName` properties.

```js
planNames: string;

this.planNames = (plans.map(plan => plan.planName)).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + ', ' + curr);
```

And use it the template

```html
<p> User 1 is enrolled in {{ planNames }} </p>
```

#### Question 2

You could bind member variables to the `href` attribute using either data binding notation or interpolation.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let plan of plans">
  <a href="#{{ plan?.planCode }}_details">{{ plan?.PlanName }}</a>
</ng-container>
```

#### Update

I am not sure what you're exactly after, but to combine both the questions, you could do something like following

```html
<p>User 1 is enrolled in 
  <ng-container *ngFor="let plan of plans; let last=last">
    <a href="#{{ plan?.planCode }}_details">{{ plan?.PlanName }}</a>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!last">
      ,&nbsp;
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</p>
```

In this case you do not need the additional variable `planNames`.

Comment: Thanks for the response...but i need to add hyperlinks to the question1..User 1 is enrolled in PlanA , PlanB , PLanC  ... Here i should be abe to click on Plan A or PlanB or PLanC which should take to the detail section

Comment: @Margerine: I've updated the answer, but you need to make sure the hyperlinks actually redirect to the details. I'd recommend you to look into Angular Router to setup routes using Angular way.

Comment: Thanks That helped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
<p> User 1 is enrolled in 
  <a *ngFor="let plan of plans" href="#{{plan.planCode}}_details">{{plan.PlanName}}</a>
</p>
```